# Make a column in a ListView/SingleChildScrollView take up the REMAINING space of a screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a registration screen, the concept that I have designed on adobe XD is that the registration Screen will have the app logo in the top center, a card with approximately 3-4 textfields/areas, a button in the bottom center. Since there will be multiple cards to fill I want a circular page indicator in the center to make it easier for the user to track the remaining data to fill as well as the user wont have to fill a really long list in a single screen.

**What I have tried is**
A SingleChildScrollView with a column inside it and the column has the first registration form to fill and another column inside it that has the button with the page indicator

A Stack and a pageviewbuilder this gave me the best results in terms of layout but the only issue is that when using the keyboard the widgets will throw a renderFlew overflow

and right now a listview with the form in it and a column that has the button and the page indicator

**Things that I need:**

- the keyboard to not cause an issue with form
- the code to be practical and consistent for multiple screen sizes

**my latest code**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> registrationForms = [EmailRegistrationForm()];
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: registrationForms[0]),
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Text("Already have an account? Login!"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  PrimaryStyledButton(text: "Next", onPress: () {}),
                  CirclePageIndicator(
                    currentPageNotifier: _currentPageNotifier,
                    itemCount: registrationForms.length,
                    selectedDotColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ));
  }
```

[image]

**what is expected**

Comment: did not change anything really and the expanded cannot be wrap a column in a list view, and if expanded is used with a column and a singlechildscrollview this error is thrown RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: try wrapping it with Flexible with fit:FlexFit.loose

Comment: did not work had the same issue as i did with expanded so i ended up removing the column from inside the list view i will post my solution as an answer

Comment: expanded/flexible work when changing the structure of the code itself, inside column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this is what ended up working for me, I realized that the list view is kinda useless so the structure became as follows:
SingleChildScrollView that has a sized box (size of the screen) and a column inside the sized box, the SingleChildScrollView is to stop the issue of the keyboard pushing things up as well giving the ability to scroll while filling the data

```
return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: landingScreen.getLogoWidget(),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center, child: registrationForms[0]),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                        child: InkWell(
                          child: Text(ALREADY_REGISTERED_MSG),
                        ),
                      ),
                      PrimaryStyledButton(text: NEXT, onPress: () {
                      }, ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                        child: CirclePageIndicator(
                          currentPageNotifier: _currentPageNotifier,
                          itemCount: registrationForms.length,
                          selectedDotColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using SingleChildScrollView with expanded widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> registrationForms = [EmailRegistrationForm()];
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: registrationForms[0]),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Text("Already have an account? Login!"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    PrimaryStyledButton(text: "Next", onPress: () {}),
                    CirclePageIndicator(
                      currentPageNotifier: _currentPageNotifier,
                      itemCount: registrationForms.length,
                      selectedDotColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Use the Flexible widget instead of expanded. Except that you got the effect you wanted right?

Comment: did not work had the same issue as i did with expanded so i ended up removing the column from inside the list view i will post my solution as an answer

Comment: expanded/flexible work when changing the structure of the code itself, inside column